# Exporting Ad Block Plus "element hider" into uBlock

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, adblock, ublock

Despite its high memory usage, I was a happy user of AdBlock Plus for years -- not only because of the main plugin's functionality, but also (perhaps, *primarily*) because of the [Element Hider add-on](https://adblockplus.org/elemhidehelper), which allowed me to block the various stupid NAVs, ASIDEs, HEADERs, and FOOTERs cleaning up the web-pages I visit not only of advertising, but also of the screen-wasting cruft.

Unfortunately, with the upgrade of Firefox to "Quantum", the Element Hider is disabled and the interface of the new AdBlock Plus (3.x) is too silly -- and seems buggy -- to use.

So I'm trying to switch to uBlock. Can I somehow import the collection of rules I've created for AdBlock over the years?

Comment: The Element Hiding Helper didn’t add new blocking functionality by the way. It just provided the element picker tool. The rules it created were regular Adblock rules. uBlock Origin already has an element picker built-in.

Comment: Technically, you are correct. Practically, Element Helper made the technology useful -- uBlock Origin's implementation is very much inferior, a 2 to the "Helper"'s 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just copy & paste those rules to uBlock w/o tweaking anything since [uBlock supports Adblock Plus ("ABP") filter syntax](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax). Better yet, if you have those rules on github, you can also add the link to 3rd-party filters.

Oh, there are some cases that involve wildcard CSS syntax which will not work on uBlock though. You will need to port them to comply with [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS3) syntax.

For example,

```
###sidebar_ad-53821932968a3c.blue
```

will turn to

```
##.blue[id^="sidebar_ad-"]
```

Comment: Thank you. With hundreds of entries I accumulated over the years, the porting seems like a daunting undertaking. I've started blocking with uBlock anew -- and miss the Element Helper's interface every day...